# How to import a submodule alone in Python?

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have this structure:

```
.
└── module
    ├── __init__.py
    └── submodule
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── foo.py
        └── bar.py
```

In `module.submodule.__init__.py` I have this:

```
import foo
import bar
```

In `module.submodule.foo.py` I have this:

```
import very_heavy_third_party_module as vhtpm
...
```

I would like to import `bar` only, but I got slowed down by `foo` (let's imagine there is an ugly `time.sleep(3)` in both `foo` and `module/__init__.py`).

So my goal is to write this below without getting slowed down by other parts of my module:

```
from module.submodule.bar import saybar
saybar()
```

How can I just import `saybar` located in my submodule `bar`?

Comment: from module import submodule.bar.saybar ?

Comment: @Illusionist not really working. Have you tried `from datetime import datetime.now` ?

Comment: I don't know if this can be done but it looks like bar does not belong in that submodule.

Comment: **You can't**. In order to import a submodule you **must** import its package. If inside the `__init__.py` that defines the package you import all submodules you *always* end up importing all submodules and there's nothing you can really do to avoid this. To fix this: avoid putting the imports inside `__init__.py`, or just put those that are fast and leave the heavy module non-imported.

Comment: sys.path.append(r'path_to_module\module\submodule');import bar ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do import from `bar` without running `foo` is to remove `import foo` from `module.submodule.__init__.py`. This is because when you import a package/module in Python, all of the top-level code in that module (or `__init__.py` if importing a package) is run. When you run `from module.submodule.bar import saybar`, all of the top-level code in:

- `module.__init__.py`
- `module.submodule.__init__.py`
- `module.submodule.bar.py`

is run. Since `module.submodule.__init__.py` contains `import foo`, `foo` is imported and all of its top-level code (including `import very_heavy_third_party_module as vhtpm`) is run as well, causing the slowdown.

A few possible solutions are:

- Move as much code as possible out of `__init__.py`. It's a common practice to leave `__init__.py`s empty - if there's some functionality in there, you might want to consider moving it to its own module. Once the `import` lines are the only ones remaining, you can just remove them, since they make no difference with regards to namespacing.
- Relocate the `import vhtpm` in `foo.py` down from the top-level (e.g. into a function that's called by something else in the module). This isn't very clean, but might work for you if you need the optimization.